# How to know the Control is TLabel?

Tags: c++builder

```
My Environment: C++ Builder XE4
```

[how to copy all the TLabels parented with a TPanel on delphi to another TPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462866/how-to-copy-all-the-tlabels-parented-with-a-tpanel-on-delphi-to-another-tpanel)

I would like to implement above code in C++ Builder.

I do not know how to implement below in C++ Builder.

```
if ParentControl.Controls[i] is TLabel then
```

Are there any functions to get type as TLabel or some other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(ParentControl->Controls[i]) != NULL)
```

Here is a translation of that code:

```
void __fastcall CopyLabels(TWinControl *ParentControl, TWinControl *DestControl)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < ParentControl->ControlCount; ++i)
   {
       if (dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(ParentControl->Controls[i]) != NULL)
       {
           TLabel *ALabel = new TLabel(DestControl);
           ALabel->Parent = DestControl;
           ALabel->Left   = ParentControl->Controls[i]->Left;
           ALabel->Top    = ParentControl->Controls[i]->Top;
           ALabel->Width  = ParentControl->Controls[i]->Width;
           ALabel->Height = ParentControl->Controls[i]->Height;
           ALabel->Caption= static_cast<TLabel*>(ParentControl->Controls[i])->Caption;
           //you can add manually more properties here like font or another 
        }
    }
}
```

With that said, this would be slightly more efficient:

```
void __fastcall CopyLabels(TWinControl *ParentControl, TWinControl *DestControl)
{
   int count = ParentControl->ControlCount;
   for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
   {
       TLabel *SourceLabel = dynamic_cast<TLabel*>(ParentControl->Controls[i]);
       if (SourceLabel != NULL)
       {
           TLabel *ALabel = new TLabel(DestControl);
           ALabel->Parent = DestControl;
           ALabel->SetBounds(SourceLabel->Left, SourceLabel->Top, SourceLabel->Width, SourceLabel->Height);
           ALabel->Caption = SourceLabel->Caption;
           //you can add manually more properties here like font or another 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will use dynamic cast as you teach. It's very difficult to find this kind of thing on the help of C++ Builder and on the Internet. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I didn't know the SetBounds() function to set the left, top, etc. Thank you very much for this also.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **ClassType** method as:

```
if(Controls[i]->ClassType() == __classid(TLabel))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found ClassName() method.

Following seems working.

```
static bool isTCheckBox(TControl *srcPtr)
{
    if (srcPtr->ClassName() == L"TCheckBox") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That is not the equivilent of the original Delphi code.  The C++ equivilent of Delphi's `is` operator is `dynamic_cast` instead.

Comment: ClassType or dynamic_cast seem "safer" than checking a text string